# merge multiple arrayBuffer arrays to single Int16Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this code that will add some `arrayBuffer` to an array.

```
  let buffer = [];
  fetch(dataURI)
  .then( (res) => res.arrayBuffer() )
  .then( (data) => {
    buffer.push(data);
  });
```

I need to convert the resulting array into a single `Int16Array` to process it, I'm trying with this code but with no success. I'm unable to get the single Int16Array I need

```
  buffer.forEach( (item) => {
    samples = [...Int16Array.from(item)];
  });
```

Any suggestion on how I can proceed?

Answer (score 1):

maybe try this with [Array.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

```
let I16 = buffer.map(a => new Int16Array(a)).flat()
```

Comment: I need to test, I'm reading the related documentation. Will this create a single array that will contain all the arrayBuffer I have?

Comment: Yes it should do exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to map you buffers to int16 chunks and then concatenate those chunks into one array:

```
const int16Chunks = [];
let byteLength = 0;

fetch(dataURI)
  .then(res => res.arrayBuffer())
  .then(buffer => {
    const chunk = createChunk(buffer, Int16Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT);

    int16Chunks.push(chunk);
    byteLength += chunk.byteLength;
  });
```

later, when everything has been fetched:

```
const bytes = new Uint8Array(byteLength);
let offset = 0;

for (const chunk of int16Chunks) {
  bytes.set(offset, chunk);
  offset += chunk.length;
}

const result = new Int16Array(bytes.buffer);
```

finally, `createChunk` function:

```
function createChunk(buffer, step) {
  const bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
  const length = Math.ceil(bytes.length / step) * step;
  const padded = new Uint8Array(length);
  const offset = padded.length - bytes.length;
  const chunk = padded.set(offset, bytes);

  return chunk;
}
```

Comment: Tried this but not work as expected `Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: byte length of Int16Array should be a multiple of 2`

Comment: That means you got an odd number of bytes as array buffer, e.g. 1 or 3. I guess you would want to pad those with zeros.

Answer (score 1):

There is something slightly off with this question, as a `fetch` request won't ever push more than once that `data` to the buffer, but I guess it's just an example of your use case, and your `buffer` gets populated multiple times by different fetches.

In any case, what I would use instead of `.flat()` *after* all things are pushed, is the following:

```
buffer.push(...data);
// or ...
buffer.push(...new Int16Array(data));
```

This will flatten out `data` right away so that once all fetches are completed, all you have to do is:

```
const i16a = Int16Array.from(buffer);
// or ...
const i16a = new Int16Array(buffer);
```

The previous mentioned solution would instead flatten the array *without* concatenating all received data so I think it won't work, accordingly with your request.

Comment: I've already tried with spread operator but data is an arrayBuffer and will cause this error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Found non-callable @@iterator`

Comment: have you tried `buffer.push(...Int16Array.from(data));` instead? if that works, the rest wouldn't change (but I need to edit the answer if that's the case).

Comment: no, but I've tried with `buffer.push(...new Int8Array(data))` and I get this error `Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: can you try `...Int16Array.from(data)` instead? there's no call stack in there, so the error might be unrelated.

Comment: Maybe I've found a fix using this code `let i16a = new Int16Array(data); buffer.push(...i16a);` but since not all the data fetched can fit into an `Int16Array` I get this error for some requests `Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: byte length of Int16Array should be a multiple of 2`

Comment: that means your buffer is likely sent as UTF-8 ... and in such case you can always `buffer.push(...Uint8Array.from(data))` and then convert the whole buffer as Uint16Array. This might help doing that: https://github.com/WebReflection/uint8-to-utf16#readme

Comment: P.S. it makes literally no sense you had a call stack error but splitting the operation in two parts doesn't give you the exact same error ... `buffer.push(...i16a)` or `buffer.push(...Int16Array.from(data))` are *exactly* the same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately I need `Int16Array` for lamejs so I need to convert the final array to that kind of typed array

Comment: No, if I split the operation the error will not occur. As you've suggested instead using `buffer.push(...Int16Array.from(data))` will result in an empty array pushed

Comment: I've already answered that with a module that does exactly that (as string, but you have all details to convert)

Comment: Thank you, I will give a look. At the moment I'm not using any bundler like webpack, it's a simple raw chrome extension I'm working on for learning some concepts

Comment: Ok, the concept is the same. `buffer.push(...i16a)` or `buffer.push(...new Int16Array(data))` are *exactly* the same operation. This is by specs, not something me, or you, can make up. Just to be clear.

Comment: Yes, I know don't worry. I think the error is caused because I'm fetching base64 audio chunks from spotify. I will manage to find a solution, Thank you :)

Comment: That's an important detail you omitted, and base64 is not an arrayBuffer, it's plain text. You can use the encode function from this other module then: https://github.com/WebReflection/uint8-to-base64#readme (you don't need webpack for that)

Comment: I'm only using the base64 data uri only to fetch the audio chunk, the response is set to be served as arrayBuffer